# How to populate array with arrays of objects

Tags: c#, arrays

```
for (int i = 0; i < People.Length; i++) {
    People[i] = new Person(first[i], last[i], birth[i]);
}
```

Now first and last contain 20 strings and birth is a `DateTime` object that again populates the array people with 20 birthdates. I just need to know how to correctly initialize my array.

Comment: I think you should take a look [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453.aspx) MSDN tutorial to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I appreciate this but however this is more directed towards objects. Im in school and im getting a syntax error and its comming from my constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Jagged Array

ex:

You can initialize jagged arrays like this example:

```
int[][] numbers = new int[2][] { new int[] {2,3,4}, new int[] {5,6,7,8,9} };
```

You can also omit the size of the first array, like this:

```
int[][] numbers = new int[][] { new int[] {2,3,4}, new int[] {5,6,7,8,9} };
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your array with the desired size:

```
Person[] people = new Person[20];
```

To automatically use the length of, for example, `first`:

```
Person[] people = new Person[first.Length];
```

Comment: Im sorry I mean how do I populate it with my three arrays i made. two strings and lats one dateTime. My dateTime format i used is year,day,month

Comment: @thanatus: The code you showed in your question already does that.

Comment: Thats what I thought but for some reason i am getting an error in syntax saying that my constructor doesn't take three arguements. Well my seperat class takes _firstName _lastName and _birthDate.

Comment: @thanatus: Then add a constructor that takes three arguments to your Person class. :-) If you don't know how to do that, please start a new question (this has nothing to do with arrays anymore).